how to node path module in sveltekit
in express app, I used to do this
import path from 'path'

let name = path.basename('doc/img/picture.png')

Which works fine in expressjs
But in +server.ts in sveltekit
Where I do import path from 'path' I got error path not available.

I had a similar problem and had to install the type declarations for Node.js.
Try npm install --save-dev @types/node
